# Can't gain proper access to parent variable

Tags: php, oop

I am having some issue accesing the variable from the superclass.  See the two classes below:

```
abstract class StaticEndpoint {

    // API Arguments
    protected $arguments;

    // PDO Object
    protected $PDO;

    public function __construct($args) {
        $this->arguments =  $args;
        try {
                $this->PDO = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1','user', 'pass');
                $this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public abstract function executeAll();

    public abstract function executeList();

    public abstract function executeOne();

}

class Endpoint extends StaticEndpoint {

    public function __construct($args) {
        parent::__construct($args);
    }

    public function executeAll() {

    }

    public function executeList() {
        global $status,$response;

        $stmt = parent::PDO->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM users");
        $stmt->execute();
        $users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $status['code'] = 200;
        $status['message'] = "Success";
        $response = $users;
    }

    public function executeOne() {

    }
}
```

However this will not work.  I get the following error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /path/to/file/Endpoint.php on line 19`.  Line 19 is `$stmt = parent::PDO->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM users");`.  I have tried swapping this line out and using `$stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM users");` but this results in the following error `Notice: Undefined property: Endpoint::$PDO in /path/to/file/Endpoint.php on line 19`.  What is the proper way to access a variable from the super class?

Comment: It should be `parent::$PDO` -- you need the `$`. But `$this->PDO` is preferred unless you have a `$PDO` property in both classes and needed to  specifically bypass the local one to get to the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->PDO` is the proper syntax to access a public/protected field of the parent class. That error messages tells me that maybe you didn't have Endpoint properly extending StaticEndpoint when you got that error.